# Why my Async c# code never finish the run and get out without any error?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Just trying to get into C# Async programming. I'm finding difficult to understand this async part, mainly because every time I see the use of Async/Await, the await part is always attach to a Async operation coming from any API, but what if I need to wait for my own Task. I assume that making a method that return a Task is enough to have an async method and therefore I can await it.

In the next code, something is escaping from my understanding, and I'm pretty sure, that if somebody replies, I will finally get into it. The code is the following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    runAsync();
}

static async void runAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("KickOff");
    int a = await processAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Result:{0}", a);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async private Task<int> processAsync()
{
    Task<int> a = func();
    int b = await a;
    //Console.WriteLine("Result:{0}", b);
    return a.Result;
}

static private Task<int> func()
{
    int a = 0;
    Task<int> f = Task<int>.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            a++;
        }
        return a;
    });

    return f;
}
```

If I breakpoint in the statement `int b = await a;`  from method `processAsync()` I can see that the status of Task a is running, the result is "Not Yet Computed" but when I hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to await for the results, then the program leaves the execution doing nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have `runAsync` return a task and wait for it with `runAsync().Wait()`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I think I was fine in my concept of Async, my fail was more about Task comprehension than Async/Await.

Appreciate i3arnon, you made my day and my studies